# vba excel userform move to next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I recently created a VBA userform with various ActiveX controls, and I'm having trouble with the following:

1. Saving data from the userform to a worksheet
2. Entering data to the next available row in the worksheet (creating multiple records)
3. Resetting the userform for new data entry

I have a command button that uses (unsuccessfully) the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim addme As Range
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set addme = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    With ws
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.txtNeedsAnalysSum
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.txtSummaryOfTask
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.txtIntroduction
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.chkInRes
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.chkOnline
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.chk24Hr
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.chk3days
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.chkDurOther
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.cmbPrereqReq
        addme.Offset.Value = Me.cmbPrereqRec
    End With
End Sub
```

Any assistance is appreciated!

-Joe

Comment: Haven't dug in deep yet, but your `With ws` is superfluous. The Range object `addme` knows which sheet in which it resides.

Comment: And in `addme.Offset.Value` you need to specify the offset like `addme.Offset(0, 1).Value`. Afterwards resetting a textbox would be as easy like `Me.txtNeedsAnalysSum = vbNullString` and for the checkboxes `Me.chkInRes = False`. For resetting comboboxes see textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should do it:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim addme As Long
    Set ws = Sheet1
    addme = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    With ws
        ws.Cells(addme, 1).Value = Me.txtNeedsAnalysSum 'the number 1 here represents the Column A
        ws.Cells(addme, 2).Value = Me.txtSummaryOfTask 'the number 2 represents Column B
        ws.Cells(addme, 3).Value = Me.txtIntroduction
        ws.Cells(addme, 4).Value = Me.chkInRes
        ws.Cells(addme, 5).Value = Me.chkOnline
        ws.Cells(addme, 6).Value = Me.chk24Hr
        ws.Cells(addme, 7).Value = Me.chk3days
        ws.Cells(addme, 8).Value = Me.chkDurOther
        ws.Cells(addme, 9).Value = Me.cmbPrereqReq
        ws.Cells(addme, 10).Value = Me.cmbPrereqRec
    End With
        Me.txtNeedsAnalysSum = vbNullString 're-set your textboxes
        Me.txtSummaryOfTask = vbNullString
        Me.txtIntroduction = vbNullString
        Me.chkInRes = False
        Me.chkOnline = False
        Me.chk24Hr = False
        Me.chk3days = False
        Me.chkDurOther = False
        Me.cmbPrereqReq = ""
        Me.cmbPrereqRec = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  The last code (Xabier) worked perfectly.  And I learned a few things.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @JoeC. If my response has helped you, please could you mark it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want do something like:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim addme As Range
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set addme = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


        addme.Offset(,1).Value = Me.txtNeedsAnalysSum
        addme.Offset(,2).Value = Me.txtSummaryOfTask
        addme.Offset(,3).Value = Me.txtIntroduction
        addme.Offset(,4).Value = Me.chkInRes
        addme.Offset(,5).Value = Me.chkOnline
        addme.Offset(,6).Value = Me.chk24Hr
        addme.Offset(,7).Value = Me.chk3days
        addme.Offset(,8).Value = Me.chkDurOther
        addme.Offset(,9).Value = Me.cmbPrereqReq
        addme.Offset(,10).Value = Me.cmbPrereqRec

End Sub
```

You could, potentially, loop through the controls in your form and use a variable to track which column you are writing to:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim addme As Range
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set addme = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Dim cntrl As control
    Dim intCol as integer
    intCol = 0
    For Each cntrl in Me.Controls
        addme.offset(, intCol) = cntrl
        intCol = intCol + 1
    Next cntrl        
End Sub
```

That will also pick up labels and submit buttons and what have you, so YMMV.